# Count occurrences of ID in other columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query which loads employee IDs, their managers (from CEO down to direct supervisor), and then a count of the number of people in their reporting group (people who they supervise either directly or indirectly). I've figured out how to do the first part, loading employee IDs and manager hierarchy.

To simplify my question, assume the table I've created looks like:

```
EMPL_ID    MGR_1    MGR_2
001        001      
002        001      
003        001      002
004        001      002
005        001      002
006        001
007        001      006
```

So MGR_1 is the top manager (My actual data set has thousands of rows and managers all the way down to MGR_10 but this simple example should be illustrative). The end result I want would be:

```
EMPL_ID    MGR_1    MGR_2    REP_GRP
001        001               7
002        001               3
003        001      002      0
004        001      002      0
005        001      002      0
006        001               1
007        001      006      0
```

So REP_GRP is the count of the number of employees who report up to the person specified by EMPL_ID.

I've tried doing this with subqueries and case statements but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code. There might be a better solution, but this is what I could think of on the go.

```
WITH MgrCount AS (
select MGR_1 AS Mgr, COUNT(EMPL_ID) AS REP_GRP
FROM CountMGR 
WHERE MGR_1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MGR_1
UNION ALL 
select MGR_2 AS Mgr, COUNT(EMPL_ID) AS REP_GRP
FROM CountMGR 
WHERE MGR_2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MGR_2
)

SELECT EMPL_ID, MGR_1, MGR_2, COALESCE (REP_GRP, 0)
FROM CountMGR AS M
LEFT OUTER JOIN MgrCount AS C ON M.EMPL_ID = C.Mgr
```

Comment: And if I wanted to extend this to MGR_3, MGR_4,..., MGR_10, would I just add more union statements to the first query?

Comment: Also can you explain what the COALESCE function is doing/ why you used that?

Comment: COALESCE checks for null and replace with 0 (in this case)

Comment: Yes you can extend using union all till MGR_10. Coalesce is actually replacing NULL to 0. So Coalesce will check the value for REP_GRP and if finds a value then it will fetch the value, if NULL then replace NULL with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT empl_id, mgr_1, mgr_2,
       CASE WHEN empl_id = mgr_1 THEN
             (SELECT count(*) FROM employees AS e2 WHERE e.empl_id = e2.mgr_1)
            ELSE
             (SELECT count(*) FROM employees AS e2 WHERE e.empl_id = e2.mgr_2)
       END AS rep_grp
FROM employees AS e
ORDER BY empl_id;
```

which gives

```
EMPL_ID     MGR_1       MGR_2       rep_grp
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
001         001                     7
002         001                     3
003         001         002         0
004         001         002         0
005         001         002         0
006         001                     1
007         001         006         0
```

---

This is not the best database design for a hierarchy, though. You're better off tracking just the immediate manager and using recursive CTEs to calculate such figures. Example:

Given a table like:

```
EMPL_ID     mgr_id
----------  ----------
001
002         001
003         002
004         002
005         002
006         001
007         006
```

which uses a null `mgr_id` value to denote a top-level manager (Because they don't report to anybody), a query like this:

```
SELECT empl_id, mgr_id,
   (WITH RECURSIVE reports AS
     (SELECT e2.* FROM employees AS e2 WHERE e2.mgr_id = e.empl_id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT e2.*
      FROM employees AS e2
      JOIN reports AS r ON e2.mgr_id = r.empl_id)
    SELECT count(*) FROM reports) AS rep_grp
FROM employees AS e
ORDER BY empl_id;
```

generates the reporting-to numbers:

```
EMPL_ID     mgr_id      rep_grp
----------  ----------  ----------
001                     6
002         001         3
003         002         0
004         002         0
005         002         0
006         001         1
007         006         0
```

(6 instead of 7 because, again, the top-level manager doesn't report to anybody, not even themselves)

Comment: The recursive one seems like a good approach to me, but when I try to run that it's throwing back the error ORA-00905 missing keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.empl_id <> t2.mgr1 and
              t.empl_id in (t2.mgr1, t2.mgr2)
       ) as rep_grp
from t;
```

Note that this gives 6 rather than 7 for the highest level manager.  I don't think it makes sense to count that person as an employee of him or herself.

Remove the `t2.empl_id <> t2.mgr1` if you want 7 instead of 6.